# Bluemix. Monitoring and Analytics service. Automatically log out

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a node.js application. I have bound it to a "Monitoring and Analytics" service, when I click on the service I see the list of apps but when I click on the App the browser shows the four tabs of the Monitoring service and then redirect me to a web page outside Bluemix that says "IBM Performance Management (SaaS) Service Log Out" explaining that I have log out.

I'm using United-Kingdom region. I'm working with chrome 45. With Firefox is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an error on one particular server that has been corrected. It should be working again now.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache and cookies and logging back in.  Sometimes the cookies can get a little mixed up.

Comment: Same behavior. Chrome -> Settings -> Clear browsing data -> Cookies and other site and plugin data -> Since the beginning of time.